# If runs twice wkhtmltopdf lib at the same time, why it will occur only data document without any table or image which is displayed in html file

Tags: html, c++, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

```
void HtmltoPDF::ConvertHtmltoPDF(std::string htmlTextData)
{
wkhtmltopdf_global_settings *global_settings;
wkhtmltopdf_object_settings *object_settings;
wkhtmltopdf_converter *Converter;

wkhtmltopdf_init(true);


global_settings = wkhtmltopdf_create_global_settings();

wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(global_settings, "out", "..\\DownloadPDF\\Example.pdf"); 

object_settings = wkhtmltopdf_create_object_settings(); // create input **object** to store the setting

//const char* a = "..\\Template\\VartLitePDF.html";

//wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(object_settings, "page", a); //pathway for the html file.
//wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(object_settings, "web.enableJavascript", "true"); //enable javascript.

Converter = wkhtmltopdf_create_converter(global_settings); //create the converter to convert the page.
wkhtmltopdf_add_object(Converter, object_settings, htmlTextData.c_str());


if (!wkhtmltopdf_convert(Converter)) //Perform the actual conversion.
    fprintf(stderr, "Convertion failed!");

std::cout << "httpErrorCode : " << wkhtmltopdf_http_error_code(Converter) << std::endl;

const char* b = "..\\DownloadPDF\\Example.pdf";

HtmltoPDF::setReportGeneratedURL(b);

wkhtmltopdf_destroy_converter(Converter); //delete the object after the object is fully convert.

std::cout << wkhtmltopdf_deinit() << "\n"; //close the function after used.
}







int main()
{
string path;

cout << "Path file  : ";
cin >> path;
cout << endl;

GetData *data;
GetData::createGetDataObject(&data);
data->GetString(path);

cout << data->GetString(path) << endl << endl;


string htmltext = data->GetString(path);


cout << endl;


    HtmltoPDF *PDF;
    HtmltoPDF::createPDFObject(&PDF);
    PDF->ConvertHtmltoPDF(htmlTextData);
    cout << "ABCD" << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

htmlTextData => is a html content and convert it into string.

First of all, it ables to display a full complete PDF with tables and images. After the second run (No closed the pogram) but it shows only data document and without any tables and images..

May I know what is the reason it caused?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now, and by removing `wkhtmltopdf_deinit()` it worked. I don't know why and what other problems may arise but that's good for me so I don't think more of it.

Comment: remove wkhtmltopdf_deinit(), it generate only one PDF document file only. At this case, if you wants to generate more than one PDF document file, it won't works well(without close program).. And it generates N same PDF document(same content with previous first generate) in N times..